# regex for finding a particular file

Tags: java, regex

I want to match a file name as `"abc (1).xyz"` or `"abc (2).xyz"` or `"abc (3).xyz"` and so on, in which `abc` and `xyz` (extension) is fixed. Besides, the space+`(number)`  part is optional, i.e. the `abc.xyz` is also valid.

I have tried the below code, but it didn't returns the success response:

```
String regex = "abc\\s([0-9])\\.xyz";
        Pattern mather = Pattern.compile(regex);

        if (mather.matcher(fileName).matches()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Please suggest any solution for the same. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the parentheses are literal, use `abc\\s\\([0-9]+\\)\\.xyz"`

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, but is there any option to make brackets and digits optional in regex, as it could match "abc.ini" also?

Comment: `"abc(?:\\s+\\([0-9]+\\))?\\.xyz"`?

Comment: Yeah Thanks Wiktor, it worked for me..

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
String regex = "abc(?:\\s+\\([0-9]+\\))?\\.xyz";
```

It will match:

- `abc` - `abc`
- `(?:\\s+\\([0-9]+\\))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `\\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars
  - `\\(` - a `(`
  - `[0-9]+`  - 1+ digits
  - `\\)` - a `)`
- `\\.xyz` - a `.xyz` substring.

Since you are using `Matcher#matches()` method, the whole string match is required (as if the whole pattern was enclosed with `^` and `$` anchors, `"^abc(?:\\s+\\([0-9]+\\))?\\.xyz$"`).